# Finding fraction of liquid and solid from isomorphous alloy phase diagram

Tags: metallurgy, material-science

**if alpha of 82% B and liquid of 57% B are in equilibrium in an alloy of 73% B,the fraction of liquid is?**

I know formula for it, but confused in finding property.
Any help will be of great use & will be highly obliged. Thanks